# How to Trace and Process Stream with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I am writing an application which will make a REST HTTP call and receive JSON back in the response body. The response body could be large and the content variable so I am wanting to handle it as a stream and process the content to decide which parts I want to deserialize.

I am able to perform my parsing and deserialize the objects I want using a StreamReader (passing in the HttpResponseMessage.Content, read as a stream) and a JsonTextReader. However, as the JsonTextReader pulls data from the stream, I would also like to trace the raw JSON to a file so that we have the raw response recorded (for diagnostics).

For example, my code:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer()

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpContentStream))
using (var textReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    textReader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

    while (textReader.Read())
    {
        // Code which looks at the tokens in the text reader and
        // figures out what to throw away, what to deserialize and
        // what the next type to deserialize will be (stored in someType)

       Type someType = null;

       // Deserialize an object that we're interested in.
       // This advances the textReader to the next token
       // after then end of this object (I.E. More than one token)

       var someObject = serializer .Deserialize(textReader, someType);

    }
}
```

Is there a way to also have Json.Net trace out the string that its reading as it pulls characters off the stream? I understand that this could generate a large file!

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: As per https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm I imagine you could potentially use `reader.Value`?

Comment: there is always the option to write a custom stream writer/reader that just writes/reads to two streams.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I looked into that but reader.Value is null for a lot of the token types (for example, StartObject, EndObject). I would therefore have to write some kind of converter. Plus, the serializer.Deserialize call skips over multiple tokens which I would have no opportunity to access.